# How do I restore the original Grub2 boot loader?

Tags: boot, grub2, burg

I wanted to try out the Burg boot loader, so I typed in the following commands:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install burg
That was just slowing down my boot, and I didn't have any control about the ubuntu recovery manager, besides, it was booting up ubuntu safe mode. I re-installed grub2 by entering:
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
That didn't work too well... It ended up making my machine put up a grub command line. I'm trying to restore the grub OS choice menu, but don't know the commands to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the second command:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

And you're sure your Ubuntu is on sda5, I assume.  Use

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to be sure.

I also assume you're running this from a LiveCD.

Comment: I typed those into grub, but all it gives me is "unknown command sudo". PS: What's the live cd?